# Add row to SQL query results with totals of certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a sql query

```
select * from orderTable
```

that returns:

[image]

I want to have the query return an additional row that has orderId = 'Total' and the sum of GrossAmt, Payments, NetAmt with the remaining fields being empty, like this:

[image]

What I've tried:

```
select isnull(OrderId, 'Total') as OrderId, GrossAmt
from    (
        select OrderId, SUM(GrossAmt) as GrossAmt
        from orderTable
        group by OrderId with rollup
    ) as OT
```

Which will return the last row with Total and sum of GrossAmt, but when I try to add, say StoreId like:

```
select isnull(OrderId, 'Total') as OrderId, GrossAmt, StoreId
    from    (
            select OrderId, SUM(GrossAmt) as GrossAmt, StoreId
            from orderTable
            group by OrderId, StoreId with rollup
        ) as OT
```

Then I get double the results with a duplicate for each row only with a null value for StoreId.

I just had the idea to switch the place of OrderId and StoreId in the above query and that has given me my closest results. I have exactly what I want, only there are 2 total rows at the bottom, one with a null StoreId.

Comment: what do you want to return in `StoreID`?

Comment: I just want it empty, so null, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION to make it a single table:

```
     select * from
        (
        select cast(OrderId as Varchar) as OrderId, Custname, GrossAmt, Payments, NetAmt, StoreId, StaffName
        from orderTable
        UNION
        (select 'Total' as OrderId, Null as Custname, 
            Sum(GrossAmt) As GrossAmt, 
            Sum(Payments) As Payments, 
            Sum(NetAmt) As NetAmt, Null as StoreId, Null as StaffName
        from orderTable) 
        ) a
```

Notice the cast to have the word Total fit in the OrderId column

Comment: I get an error "Incorrect syntax near ')'. on the last line, it looks like there's a missing close paren, I assume for the outer select so I added one more line with a new paren, still get the error. If I change * to the fields names you get the error "Invalid column name".

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ISNULL(OrderId, 'Total') as OrderId, GrossAmt, NULL AS storeId
FROM    (
        SELECT  OrderId, SUM(GrossAmt) as GrossAmt
        FROM    orderTable
        GROUP BY
                OrderId WITH ROLLUP
        ) AS OT
```

Comment: This gives null as all storeId, I only want the Total row to have null for storeId, if I remove the "NULL AS storeId" and make it just "storeId" then I get the same as my last cast in the original question, all rows, two total rows, one with a storeId and one with a null storeId.

Comment: Shoot, it is not. My example above is a bit dumbed down from my actual query. That may have been a mistake on my part, I was trying to simplify the question. OrderTable is actually the results of query which takes data from several tables. I just checked and two tables have the OrderId field. I would have thought putting otherTableName.OrderId would do the trick but assuming substitute that in for each instance of OrderId in your query I get errors under the first OrderId, the '.' in the second one, and under "AS".